# How to rewrite the out put of field in view

Tags: views

In view for title, I have rewrite the output as link and passing other view link. But after doing this also its not taking to the page link for that node.

Why is this? I am doing mistake?

Comment: Hi @neethu, can you please eleborate the question. So I can better understand.

Comment: @PankajSachdeva: I have created view when we click on node saved it has show the another view with all other fields table related with that node, so for that node i am trying to give other child view link out put when we click on it. but its not showing.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your view's **Configure field** section of **Content: Title** you already checked the following option.

**Link this field to the original piece of content**

If this option is checked then mostly your **rewrite the output** won't work. Please check that.

[image]

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Hi, the screen shot attached is not visible for me.only half of it its visible.

Comment: Click on your title field in **edit your view -> fields section**. it will open a popup like this.

Comment: i have clicked on it specified other view url but no luck its the same

Comment: you have to untick that.

Comment: :untick ?if i untick then how can give url

Comment: if you tick that, it will link to orginal content. but in your usecase you have to link it with different content right.??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30860/discussion-between-neethu-and-abin).